# Graph editor always works in channels?

Tags: graph-editor

Does hit always need to work as individual channels?

I'm animating an object that has a "snap" animation that involves Loc and Rot.  The graph editor forces you to tell it which channel you want to edit.

I just want to edit the entire keyframe.  That's not possible?  I need to edit each channel?

Comment: what do you mean when you say that it forces you to tell which channel you want to edit? You can edit several keyframes at once, the problem being that it rarely makes sense to edit both location and rotation at the same time for example

Comment: Think of me animating a hand.  It's not going to be a perfect X,Y or Z straight where I can edit on the editor.  The hand movement will be a combination of the 3.  Am I suppose to go into each channel and edit the curves manually?  Isn't there a way I can edit the whole hand movement?  For example if I want a bounce at the end, I'll need to edit X, Y and Z to have a bounce interpolation.  I just want to look at it as one motion and put the bounce in.

Comment: let's say that the object move on bothe X and Y, you can edit X and Y at the same time in the Graph Editor, it may not be always easy though

Comment: I don't see how they can't include it as a feature... I mean not every animation is linear where you can do 1 axis at a time.  I wonder of Maya has a "whole" graph editor.